# Azure Appservice - Bitbucket Deploy error

Tags: azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I' trying to deploy my website that is completely running in local to Azure App Service through Bitbucket and it fails.

I'm new to Azure, could enlighten me ?
Here's the log

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
SystemFrameWork -> D:\home\site\repository\SystemFrameWork\bin\Release\SystemFrameWork.dll
DataAccess -> D:\home\site\repository\DataAccess\bin\Release\DataAccess.dll
SEI-Utils -> D:\home\site\repository\SEI-Utils\bin\Release\SEIUtils.dll
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "4.5.0.0" [] to Version "6.0.0.0" [D:\home\site\repository\WebUI\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> [D:\home\site\repository\WebUI\SMC.WEB-UI.csproj]
SMC.WEB-UI -> D:\home\site\repository\WebUI\bin\SEI.dll
Transformed Web.config using       
D:\home\site\repository\WebUI\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
D:\local\Temp\8d59617f714bd52.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3010,5): error : Copying file Content\buz\images\.DS_Store to D:\local\Temp\8d59617f714bd52\Content\buz\images\.DS_Store failed. Could not find file 'Content\buz\images\.DS_Store'. [D:\home\site\repository\WebUI\SMC.WEB-UI.csproj]
 Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\WebUI\SMC.WEB-UI.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d59617f714bd52";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\71.10313.3301 \bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

The key error is:

```
error : Copying file Content\buz\images\.DS_Store to D:\local\Temp\8d59617f714bd52\Content\buz\images\.DS_Store failed. Could not find file 'Content\buz\images\.DS_Store'.
```

My guess is that you forgot to add this file to your repo. you'd probably see the same error if you did a local deployment using a clean clone of your repo. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-site-correctly-deploys-locally) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, i do see that but there is no .DS_Store file in Content\buz\images\ . That make me so confused. After a small google research i know that DS_Store is a file that exist on Mac but my project code on Windows and i have no idea what happened here.
Do you have any idea for that error?. Best regard.

Comment: Did you try the clean local deploy test described in that link?